# Ignorar arquivos da pasta target

Tags: git, maven

Como faço para ignorar os arquivos da pasta `target` do Maven?

Quero ignorá-las para que o `git` não veja os arquivos.

Comment: O git possui um arquivo que você pode criar chamado .gitignore ... É um arquivo de texto que cada linha corresponde ao "caminho" que você pretende que ele ignore. Como você quer a pasta target do maven, crie o arquivo .gitignore na raiz do seu projeto e coloque uma linha assim: target/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No arquivo `.gitignore` inclua a sintaxe `*/target/*`.

Isso faz com que o git ignore tudo o que estiver dentro de **qualquer pasta chamada** `target`

---

Vale a leitura da [documentação oficial do git](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) sobre o `.gitignore`. Lá é descrito em detalhes os padrões que podem ser utilizados para ignorar arquivos e pastas do projeto.